# Does John mean by "Son of perdition" "Sons of perdition" in John 17:12?

Tags: greek, john

John 17:12, (DRB):

> While I was with them, I kept them in thy name. Those whom thou gavest me have I kept; and none of them is lost, but **the son of perdition**, that the scripture may be fulfilled.

Does John mean by the singular "Son" the plural "Sons" in John 17:12?

i.e: Son of perdition=Sons of perdition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operative Greek phrase in John 17:12 is ὁ υἱὸς τῆς ἀπωλείας = the son of destruction.

The word υἱὸς (huios) is singular.

The word "perdition" or "destruction" translates ἀπωλείας and is used as a proper name for Satan in Rev 9:11. Thus, "son of destruction" would refer to someone who follows Satan and his ways - see John 8:44.

Most understand this phrase to refer to Judas who betrayed Jesus and then suicided.  Ellicott observes:

> The term, "son of perdition," is a well-known Hebrew idiom, by which
>   the lack of qualitative adjectives is supplied by the use of the
>   abstract substantives, which express that quality. A disobedient child
>   is, e.g., "a son of disobedience;" other common instances are
>   "children of light," "children of darkness." A "son of perdition" is
>   one in whose nature there is the quality expressed by "perdition." The
>   phrase is used in Isaiah 57:4 to express the apostacy of the
>   Israelites (in English version, "children of transgression"). It
>   occurs once again in 2Thessalonians 2:3, of the "man of sin."

Barnes observes:

> But the son of perdition … The term son was given by the Hebrews to
>   those who possessed the character described by the word or name
>   following. Thus, sons of Belial - those who possessed his character;
>   children of wisdom those who were wise, Matthew 11:19. Thus Judas is
>   called a son of perdition because he had the character of a destroyer.
>   He was a traitor and a murderer. And this shows that he who knew the
>   heart regarded his character as that of a wicked man one whose
>   appropriate name was that of a son of perdition.

Comment: could the idiom,also, be applied to Satan and his angels and his Human subservient, beside Judas the betrayer.

Comment: could you include your comment in your answer?

Comment: @salah How can Satan/Lucifer/Diabolos be 'the son of' perdition ? Is he not the father of it ?

Comment: @NigelJ I think rhetorically, Son of perdition may means also, Father of perdition.

Comment: I struggle to understand you @salah. You say 'son' = 'sons' in your question and you say that 'son' means 'father' in your comment. Language does not work the way you are trying to make it work. But I shall add no more and leave you to it. Regards.

Comment: @NigelJ all these accepted rhetorically.

Comment: @salah I have no idea what you mean by that. A rhetorical question is one that seeks none to answer it. It is a statement, worded as a question, but no response is expected. Do you mean you are not open to logical argument ?

Comment: @NigelJ to understand the Holy Books we should use Dialectic using two levels of Logic: - the formal logic, - the higher logic. The Text of Holy Books is Dynamic not Static.